# ¿Como hago que mi codigo no termine y no escriba algo infinitamente?

Tags: python

Hola estoy haciendo un "chatbot" en python.Ya se que no es la manera mas optima de hacerlo,pero igual esto me va a servir para otros proyectos.
Mi pregunta es: ¿Como hago para que sigas podiendo hablar despues de el primer input?
ya intente con while pero repite muchísimas veces la respuesta.
Claro,podría poner mas inputs o algo así,pero eso limitaría cuantas veces podes responder al bot.
Aquí mi código:

```
    print("soy un chatbot,dime hola")

#Las palabras que deseo verificar
claves=['vos', 'bot']
claves2=['hola','Hola']
mensaje=[]

msj = input()

#Esto separará las palabras del input
mensaje2 = msj.split()

mensaje.append(mensaje2)

if any(word in msj for word in claves):
    print("No,vos sos el bot")

if any(word in msj for word in claves2):
    print("Hola")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si bien en tu pregunta dices que has puesto un `while` y que

> repite muchísimas veces la respuesta

La solución, tal como está planteada la pregunta es justamente un `while`. Obviamente es de suma importancia **que está dentro del ciclo** y que no.

Una forma simple de hacerlo es la siguiente:

```
claves=['vos', 'bot']
claves2=['hola','Hola']

while True:
    msj = input()
    
    if any(word in msj for word in claves):
        print("No, vos sos el bot")
    
    if any(word in msj for word in claves2):
        print("Hola")
```